# Issues with Angular Material Dialog Boxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code to generate a dialog but it doesn't show up. When I click on a button to show the dialog, I only see a dark layer on the page but no dialog. When I click on the dark layer, it disappears.

I declare my angular module and its dependencies on ngMaterial here. I declare a controller here and it depends on "$mdDialog, $mdMedia".

```
$scope.showAbortSessionForm = function(event){

            var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  && $scope.customFullscreen;
          $mdDialog.show({
                controller: DialogController,
                templateUrl: 'app/views/stop.html',
                //template: '<div>testing</div>',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: event,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: useFullScreen
        }).then(function(){
                $scope.status = "ddddd";
            }, function(){
                $scope.status = "tttttt";
            });
        };

       function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $scope.hide = function() {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };

            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };

            $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                $mdDialog.hide(answer);
            };
        }
```

Stop.html

```
<md-dialog>
<md-content>
<div>
    <form>
       <div><label>Name:</label></div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
        <div><label>B:</label></div>
        <textarea type="text" placeholder="blog"></textarea>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            <button>Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
</md-content>
</md-dialog>
```

index.html (this is where I click on a button to show a dialog):

```
<div>
 <md-button  ng-click="showAbortSessionForm($event)">
Abort
</md-button>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the DOM tree and see if the dialog is appearing there? If it is, then maybe there is something wrong with the css. It would be easier to help you if you provide a Plunker with all the necessary code.

Comment: @PrinceJohn my code doesn't use any CSS. So there is no problem with CSS at the moment. I just want to dialog to appear and later i will think about css

Comment: Okay, then one of my questions still remains. Also, it would still be easier to help you if you provide us a Plunker.